# Network bonding isn't working correctly

Tags: networking, interface, network-bonding

Hey guys I'm having trouble setting up Ubuntu Bonding, following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding).

My `interfaces` file looks like this:

```
auto eth0  
iface eth0 inet manual  
bond-master bond0  

auto eth1  
iface eth1 inet manual  
bond-master bond0  

auto bond0  
auto iface inet static  
address 10.1.10.30  
netmask 255.255.255.0  
dns-nameservers 10.1.10.50  
gateway 10.1.10.2  
bond-mode balance-rr  
bond-miimon 100  
bond-lacp-rate 1  
bond-slaves none
```

I can ping Google and my external static IP from another computer on another ISP (I assigned it a static one-to-one NAT address with the router and also disabled the router's firewall for troubleshooting). However, from the Ubuntu machine, I can't ping it's gateway 10.1.10.2 (even though it uses it to get to Google lol) and I can't ping any other internal address.

If I comment out the bonding and only use eth0 or eth1 everything works just fine.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in this line:

```
auto bond0
auto iface inet static
address 10.1.10.30
```

It should be:

```
auto bond0
iface inet static
address 10.1.10.30
```

Answer (score 2):

Version 13.04 includes network bonding. Very easy to use and you can select each real network connection that will be part of the virtual (bond) network.

[image]