# Unable To Use Ethernet in Ubuntu 19.04 on Asus TUF FX504

Tags: drivers, kernel, ethernet, asus, 19.04

First of all, i am not asking this question as soon as i noticed this issue. But the thing is i purchased this asus tuf fx504 3 months ago and it was all working with genuine windows. On 2nd day i installed ubuntu 19.04(development branch) and noticed this issue. I know this hardware is new, even there was issues with touchpad also and also sensors not detect acpi fan. So, i waited for newer kernel for better driver support.

I saw r8169 related files under driver>net>ethernet in mainline kernel so i fresh installed ubuntu 19.04 LTS and updated kernel to [5.2.0-050200rc7](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.2-rc7/).

**What changed ?**

- Previously there was not ethernet (Wired) option in setting/network but after updating kernel i got that option.
- Then i got connecting status as shown in this picture -> [connecting status under notification panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5syL.png)
- After sometimes when it fails to connect showing this alert box -> [Activation of network connection failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYahm.png) which goes for infinite loop.

**uname output**

```
$ uname -r
5.2.0-050200rc7-generic
```

**ifconfig output**

```
enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::898a:1463:6579:97e0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 04:92:26:6e:ab:1b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1371  bytes 178614 (178.6 KB)
        TX errors 606  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1968  bytes 168097 (168.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1968  bytes 168097 (168.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.80  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 fe80::3488:9802:814c:3f07  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2409:4062:2296:2aa8:9659:df17:a617:ab55  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2409:4062:2296:2aa8:f43b:ea6e:838f:13c3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 18:1d:ea:36:2f:7c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 23196  bytes 19937226 (19.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15628  bytes 4134485 (4.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

As i searched for existing issues, i found out all are having ethernet interface named as `eth0` but as you can see i have `enp3s0`, why ?, later i found that it renamed from eth0 to enp3s0 in dmesg.

```
[    1.638046] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: renamed from eth0
[   10.305777] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
[   11.773703] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   11.773720] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
[   11.873260] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
[   13.458759] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   13.534198] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
[   15.151133] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   15.226573] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
[   16.814176] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   16.887538] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
[   18.475925] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   18.548917] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
[   20.181428] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Up - 10Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   20.264971] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
```

In dmesg log as you can see i sometimes it logs link is ready then it goes down-up-down and it continues forever.

I was planning to install kernel 5.2 as it got some update in r8169 main source 10 days at the time of asking this question, but due to failed build of https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.2/, couldn't install it.

It will be very helpful if anyone describes the reason/workaround/fix for this isuue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, check this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062390/activation-of-network-connection-failed-for-ethernet-connection

Comment: Looks like an autonegotiation issue: Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1098748/344926) and change `enp5s0` in that answer to `enp3s0` for your use case.  If that helps, please leave a comment @Fabby **0:-)**

Comment: It's showing cable unplugged all the time. Dropping packets are later stuff. Why it's not detecting cable ?