# UBUNTU: clean, 958917/30883840 files, 22643659/123523840 blocks

Tags: boot, gnome, gdm

I have an issue with Ubuntu 18.04. I was preparing a presentation and I had to force the shut down since the screen was blocked. When I rebooted this was the message (on black screen), no more. I have tried to do different things and the most relevant lines are:

1)Started GNOME Display Manager.ever.tcher Service....system changes.pp link was shut down

2)Stopping user manager for UID120....

I trided with systemcl status display-manager from root:

gdm-service - GNOME Display manager
Loaded:loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static; vendor preset enabled)
Active:Inactive(dead)

I tried to check with journalctl to understand a bit more and apparenly this is the first reboot since I have installed a huge software (suspicious). I would not be surprised if there is some mismatching. I have isolated all the " install " in dpkg.log when I installed the software, but I don't know if the solution can be to remove them one by one since they are quite a lot.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade` If you run into a `dpkg` error, run `sudo apt -f install` This question is [possibly a duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164101/167115). Please let us know if this doesn't work and I will retract my close vote.